# ObjectMapper ignores some fileds when mapping to JSON

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

So my issue is that when mapping a class to JSON, it won't map all the fields the class has

**Card**:

```
public class Card {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private StatusCard status;
    private List<String> CardHistory;
    public enum StatusCard{TODO, INPROGRESS, TOBEREVISED, DONE};

    public Card(String name, String desc){
        this.name = name;
        description = desc;
        status = StatusCard.TODO;
        CardHistory = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Card(){}

    // getters and setters
}
```

This class is used within another class, in an
`ArrayList<Card> cardList`, but when I map this class to JSON, this is the only fields it maps

JSON:

```
... "cardList":[{"name":"test","status":"TODO"}] ...
```

and I can't figure out why. This is the method that adds a new card by the server:

```
public String addCard(String projectName, String cardName, String desc, String nickUtente) {
    if (projects.isEmpty())
        return "No projects are currently present";
    if (projectName.isEmpty() || cardName.isEmpty() || desc.isEmpty() || nickUtente.isEmpty())
        return "Missing one or more arguments";

    for (Project p : projects) {
        if (p.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(projectName)){
            if (!p.isMember(nickUtente))
                return nickUtente + " does not belong to the project";
            String code = p.addCard(cardName, desc);
            if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
                try {
                    om.writeValue(projectFile,projects);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return code;
        }
    }
    return "Project " + projectName + " not found";
}
```

This is the `Project` class using classes from `com.fasterxml.jackson` if you need to know:

```
public class Project implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private String nickUtente;
    private ArrayList<Card> cardList;
    private ArrayList<String> users;
    private ArrayList<String> TODO;
    private ArrayList<String> INPROGRESS;
    private ArrayList<String> TOBEREVISED;
    private ArrayList<String> DONE;
    private String MulticastAddress;
    private int port;

    /*
    @JsonIgnore
    private File projDir;
    @JsonIgnore
    private final ObjectMapper map;
    */

    public Project(String name, String nickUtente, String multiaddr, int port) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nickUtente = nickUtente;
        cardList = new ArrayList<>();
        users = new ArrayList<>();
        users.add(nickUtente);
        TODO = new ArrayList<>();
        INPROGRESS = new ArrayList<>();
        TOBEREVISED = new ArrayList<>();
        DONE = new ArrayList<>();
        MulticastAddress = multiaddr;
        this.port = port;
        // map = new ObjectMapper();
        // map.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        // projDir = new File("./BackupCards/" + name);
        // if(!projDir.exists()) projDir.mkdir();
    }

    public Project(){
        // this.map = new ObjectMapper();
        // map.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    }
    
    // getters and setters

    public boolean isMember(String user){
        if(users.isEmpty())
            return false;
        for(String s : users) {
            if (user.equals(s))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String addMember(String s) {
        if (s.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Missing name");
            return "err";
        }
        if (users.contains(s)) {
            System.out.println("Member exists already");
            return "err";
        }
        users.add(s);
        return "ok";
    }

    public String addCard(String cardName, String desc){
        if(cardName.isEmpty() || desc.isEmpty())
            return "Missing name and/or description";
        Card c = new Card(cardName, desc);
        cardList.add(c);
        TODO.add(cardName);
        /* 
        File cardFile = new File(projDir + "/" + cardName + ".json");
        if (!cardFile.exists()) {
            try {
                cardFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
        //Backup card file
        try {
            map.writeValue(cardFile, c);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        return "ok";
    }

    public String moveCard(String cardName, String startingList, String destList){
        if(cardName.isEmpty() || startingList.isEmpty() || destList.isEmpty())
            return "Missing one or more arguments";
        for(Card c : cardList){
            if(c.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(cardName)){
                switch(destList){
                    case "TODO":
                        if(startingList.equals("TODO"))
                            return "Card is already in " + startingList;
                        return "Cannot move card back to TODO";
                    case "INPROGRESS":
                        if(startingList.equals("INPROGRESS"))
                            return "Card already is in INPROGRESS";
                        if(startingList.equals("DONE"))
                            return "Card is done. Cannot change status anymore";
                        if(TODO.contains(cardName)){
                            TODO.remove(cardName);
                            INPROGRESS.add(cardName);
                            c.setStatus("INPROGRESS");
                            c.getCardHistory().add(startingList);
                            //System.out.println("Card moved from TODO to INPROGRESS");
                            return "ok";
                        }
                        if(TOBEREVISED.contains(cardName)){
                            TOBEREVISED.remove(cardName);
                            INPROGRESS.add(cardName);
                            c.setStatus("INPROGRESS");
                            c.getCardHistory().add(startingList);
                            //System.out.println("Card moved from TOBEREVISED to INPROGRESS");
                            return "ok";
                        }
                        return "Card not found";
                    case "TOBEREVISED":
                        if(!startingList.equals("INPROGRESS"))
                            return "Can only move to TOBEREVISED from INPROGRESS";
                        if(INPROGRESS.contains(cardName)){
                            INPROGRESS.remove(cardName);
                            TOBEREVISED.add(cardName);
                            c.setStatus("TOBEREVISED");
                            c.getCardHistory().add(startingList);
                            //System.out.println("Card moved FROM INPROGRESS TO TOBEREVISED");
                            return "ok";
                        }
                    case "DONE":
                        if(startingList.equals("TODO"))
                            return "Cannot move card to DONE from TODO";
                        if(INPROGRESS.contains(cardName)){
                            INPROGRESS.remove(cardName);
                            DONE.add(cardName);
                            c.getCardHistory().add(startingList);
                            c.setStatus("DONE");
                            //System.out.println("Moved card from INPROGRESS to DONE");
                            return "ok";
                        }
                        if(TOBEREVISED.contains(cardName)){
                        TOBEREVISED.remove(cardName);
                        DONE.add(cardName);
                        c.setStatus("DONE");
                        c.getCardHistory().add(startingList);
                        //System.out.println("Moved card from TOBEREVISED to DONE");
                        return "ok";
                        }
                        return "Card not found";
                    }
                }
            }
        return "Card not found";
    }

    public void showMembers() {
        if (users.isEmpty())
            System.out.println("No user belongs to this project");
        for (String s : users)
            System.out.println(s);
    }

    public void showCards() {
        if (TODO.isEmpty() && INPROGRESS.isEmpty() && TOBEREVISED.isEmpty() && DONE.isEmpty())
            System.out.println("No cards to be shown");
        if (TODO.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No cards TODO");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cards TODO:");
            for (String s : TODO)
                System.out.println(s);
        }
        if (INPROGRESS.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No cards IN PROGRESS");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cards INPROGRESS:");
            for (String s : INPROGRESS)
                System.out.println(s);
        }
        if (TOBEREVISED.isEmpty())
            System.out.println("No cards TOBEREVISED");
        else {
            System.out.println("Cards TOBEREVISED:");
            for (String s : TOBEREVISED)
                System.out.println(s);
        }
        if (DONE.isEmpty())
            System.out.println("No cards DONE");
        else {
            System.out.println("Cards DONE:");
            for (String s : DONE)
                System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public Card getCard(String name) {
        if (cardList.isEmpty())
            return null;
        for (Card c : cardList){
            if (c.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
                return c;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<UserStatusInfo> getCardList() {
        if(cardList.isEmpty())
            return null;
        List<UserStatusInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Card c : cardList)
            list.add(new UserStatusInfo(c.getName(),c.getStatus()));
        return list;
    }

  /*  public void delProjDir(){
        try {
            Files.walk(projDir.toPath()).sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).map(Path::toFile)
                    .forEach(File::delete);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
*/
}
```

Comment: The most important part of the code is missing: the way you map the objects. We also cannot figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: edit: added when a card gets 'added' and also the Project class, hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
public List<UserStatusInfo> getCardList() {
    if(cardList.isEmpty())
        return null;
    List<UserStatusInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Card c : cardList)
        list.add(new UserStatusInfo(c.getName(),c.getStatus()));
    return list;
}
```

You have private property `ArrayList<Card> cardList` and public method  `List<UserStatusInfo> getCardList()`. Since ObjectMapper follows JavaBean conventions during serialization it only accesses public properties and public getter methods, so when `cardList` is mapped into JSON, not `cardList` property is actually serialized, but result of `getCardList()` method invocation hence not `Card` instances are serialized but `UserStatusInfo` instances (that seem to have only `name` and `status`).

You have to create `ArrayList<Card> getCardList()` method that returns `cardList` property, and rename current `List<UserStatusInfo> getCardList()` to something else

**OR**

Extend `UserStatusInfo` class so that it has all corresponding properties from `Card`

Comment: Thank you so much Nikolai, I simply renamed getCardList() into getCardListInfo() and added the proper getter. It works now, cheers!